# Right way to process database errors in golang app

Tags: go

I have simple web app on Go. Logging of errors is important part of app.
Errors can be deived on:

a) Database errors - when interact with Database we need log all errors are occured
b) Input parameters, logic errors

My typical handler looks like:

```
func handler(r,w) {
  var client models.Client
  err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&client)
  log.Error(err) // if error was

  err = client.Validate()
  log.Error(err) // if error was

  err = client.Save()
}
...
func (client *Client) Save() error {
   _, err := db.Exec(`insert into client ....`, client.data())
   if err != nil {
     log.Error(err)
     return err
   }
   ...
}
```

Look at the *Client.Save() method. When DB error occures we log it.
My logger takes file:line where error occures.

I think that it's better way that database package processes errors itself.
For example, it's good to have some Database type which logs all errors inside methods Exec(), Query, QueryRow with taking file:line where in client code errors occures.

```
type Database struct {
}
func (d *Database) Exec(...) result, error {
      res, err := d.db.Exec()
      if err != nil {
        log.Error(err, calldepth=3) // calldepth=3 to show place in client code where errors occures
         return nil, err
     }
}
```

So, we can rewrite out method *Client.Save() mehtod to reduce error processing in client code:

```
func (client *Client) Save() error {
   _, err := db.Exec(`insert into client ....`, client.data()) // error will processed in Exec
   if err != nil {
     return err
   }
   ...
}
```

Whats is right way to process errors of Database in model-controller app?
How to reduce error processing across code?
May be there are database packages with built in features

Comment: My preferred way of handling errors in a Go webapp is to bubble all errors up to the controller/handler functions.  This allows the proper status code to be returned to the client.  I also don't log errors at all in the package that handles the database connections, just return the error.  I feel this is a matter of personal preference though.  I think the way you are doing it is fine as well.

Comment: From code reusability point of view I think it's better not to process errors in the database package, but just return the errors to the caller. That way the caller can always decide how to process and log the error, since that might vary from case to case.

Comment: Both @threeve and jussius are correct: don't log in libraries. Bubble up, and use something like https://github.com/pkg/errors to wrap/add context to errors as you bubble them up the call-stack.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be that wrapping errors can help. I have written very simple errorwrap library which add file,line as context to the normal error (based on the https://github.com/pkg/errors, and https://github.com/juju/errors packages) . After some testing this approach have found small problem - compare wrapped error with errors from standart packages, for example, errwrap.Wrap(sql.ErrNoRows) != sql.ErrNoRows. In client code we need do unwrap error back with type assertion: e.(*errwrap.Err).Cause()